# How can i split a string using two delimeters with one being double tab?

Tags: java, split

I'm creating a parser in java and what i'm parsing is separated by a tab, and at one point it is separated by a double tab.

Here's what i tried. The output only shows as if it is being split by one tab.

Here's my code to split:

```
String[] array1 = nextline.split("(\t)|(\t{2})");
```

i've also tried

```
String[] array1 = nextline.split("(\t)|(\t\t)");
```

Comment: Try putting the two tabs first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about `\\t{1,2}`?

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    String s = "ONE\tTWO\t\tTHREE";
    String[] d = s.split("\\t{1,2}");
    for(String e : d) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

Output should be

```
ONE
TWO
THREE
```

If you need to split on any number of tabs then you should use

`\\t+`

If you need to split on any whitespace then

`\\s+`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza even better, but it depends if OP doesn't want to split on more than 2

Comment: I only need it to split on two. This works perfectly thanks for the help.

Comment: But just out of curiosity what would you do?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `Foo|FooFoo` as in regex then based on fact that regex is been executed from left to right regex-engine will try to match `Foo` before `FooFoo`. So even if String will contain `FooFoo` `Foo` from regex will be used first and since it will match (twice) regex engine do not see the need to also check other variant from regex `FooFoo`.

So if you will want to split on `Foo|FooFoo` regex will split on this places

```
ABCFooBARFooFooDEF
   \|/   \|/\|/
    |     |  +-----match
    |     +--------another match     
    +--------------and another match
```

so this string will be split this way

```
ABC|BAR||DEF
```

producing array

```
["ABC", "Bar", "", "DEF"]
```

To solve this problem you have few options.

- you can move `FooFoo` before `Foo` creating `FooFoo|Foo` so now `FooFoo` will be checked before `Foo`
- you can use greedy quantifier like `Foo{1,2}` which means "try to between one and two `Foo` and pick as many as you can (greedy)".

So you can try with

- `split("\t\t|\t")`
- or `split("\t{1,2}")`.